# Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ListItem`, expected a ReactNode

Tags: reactjs, firebase, lodash

I build an app along with tutorial "Chat app. Building real-time app with React, Flux, Firebase and Webpack" and I met a problem I cannot deal with. Basically I try to pull channels Ive set up in Firebase to my store in React but something is wrong. Here is wrong part of code:

```
import alt from '../alt/index.js';
import Actions from '../actions/index.js';
import {decorate, bind, datasource} from 'alt-utils/lib/decorators';
import ChannelSource from '../sources/ChannelSource.jsx';
import _ from 'lodash';

@datasource(ChannelSource)
@decorate(alt)
class ChatStore {
constructor(){
 this.state = {user: null};
}

@bind(Actions.channelsReceived)
receivedChannels(channels){
let selectedChannel;
_(channels)
  .keys()
  .map((key, index) =>{
    channels[key].key = key;
    if (index == 0){
      channels[key].selected = true;
      selectedChannel = channels[key];
    }
  })
  .value();
console.log(channels);

this.setState({
  channels,
  selectedChannel
});
}
}

 export default alt.createStore(ChatStore);
```

In the tutorial there is used function chain: `keys().each().value()` to pull channels, but in my app it doesn't worked out so I tried to use .map() rather than .each(), but it doesnt work too.

a browser shows warning and error connected just with this part of code:

Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ListItem`, expected a ReactNode. Check the render method of `Channel`.
'children' of ListItem are just channels pulled from Firebase.

And here is an error also connected with this issuse:
 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, key, selected}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `ListItem`.

I tried everything but i stacked here and cannot move further. Thanks for any help.